# What options does CiviCRM provide for equipment management?

Tags: custom-fields, civibooking

I am just starting to configure a CiviCRM implementation for my organization. As well as managing membership, we would also like to use it to manage equipment (boats being the top priority).

**Option 1**

It seems like there are a number of ways to go about this task. The first would be to create a contact type and add custom fields with boat information (manufacturer, age, size, etc.). Then, I could use the relationships functionality to assign ownership of the boat to a specific group. Then perhaps use the events or meetings to allocate to specific user(s) for some time?

**Option 2**

Another option could be the CiviBooking extension? Here I would create a resource like a meeting room. This seemed like the perfect solution until I started setting it up. It doesn't look like I can add custom fields to resources or ownership of a resource. It also has extra functionality like quantity and price that we don't care about.

The way we would like the handle resource management, whether it is boats, meeting rooms or anything else, would be to have a certain subset of contacts (administrators, board members, whatever), would be able schedule these resources and accept any payment if needed. Any old contact wouldn't have this permission.

**Am I on the right track with either of my options or is there a better way entirely to do this?**

Comment: What CMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using WordPress.